# Using C# and ODP.NET and Oracle, how do you get an associative array (pl/sql table) from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, odp.net

Using C# 4.0 and ODP.NET.  We have a stored procedure that is part of a package that takes two in parameters and returns a pl/sql table.

I have googled for hours and have found many examples of code here and elsewhere where you pass an array to a stored procedure, but have not found a single example where you get a pl/sql table back.

Is this possible?  I believe it has to be but not sure anymore.

Note: I am NOT getting back a ref cursor, it is a pl/sql table (associate array)

Comment: I'm confused, you say your stored procedure returns a pl/sql table, but you ask how to do it. Is this a case of a badly phrased question? could you clarify?

Comment: why cant u use a ref cursor to access it? im not sure therea another way with odp.net